# my 2002 Ford Taurus won't start and makes no clicking ,etc noise.

Tags: starting

I went to start my car today, it turned over for a sec, then stopped and made no noise. All lights & accessories still work. First, I cleaned the battery terminals and cables to ensure clean connections - still no start. Then, with the ignition in the On position, I tried moving the gear shift several times in & out of gears, then back to park - still no start.  Then I got a boost and still no start, no noise, so not the alternator... I am thinking it is not the starter , as it should make a clicking noise right? … as that is what I had noticed with a previous car. So, I am thinking it could be the starter solenoid or the fuse or ignition relay switch. anyone know if this sounds like what I should check next? I will disconnect the battery and check the 40A fuse, but how do I know if the relay switch is gone…and with the solenoid attached to the starter, I guess I will have to take it to the shop for that to be checked. I like the old  cars where the solenoid was right up top and easy to jump… any help would be appreciated, as I don't want to sink much $$ in this car anymore

Comment: I have the exact same problem with my car but when I put it in neutral it "might start" if the car rolls forward in neutral it it start but it signals the anti theft so it cuts right off so it really serves no purpose to do that ... Did u find what it may be yet ???

Answer (score 1):

The solenoid is probably on the starter itself.  You can check if the signal is making it to the solenoid with a voltmeter while cranking the engine. You should see 12 volts.  Other possibilities are the battery cable running to the starter, fuses, ignition switch itself, and the neutral safety switch.  Try shifting it to neutral and starting, or wiggle the shifter while turning the key.